# What is the standard term for views that aren't Unitarian?

Tags: trinity, terminology, persons-of-the-trinity, non-trinitarian, unitarianism

When talking about views that aren't Trinitarian (such as LDS, JW, Christian Science, and so on) people often use the term 'Non-Trinitarian'.

Is there a standard term for views that are 'Non-Unitarian', i.e., Binitarian, Trinitarian, and perhaps other views that assert something like a multiplicity of persons in God?

Comment: Probably Non-Unitarian would be best? But it's not a category that would be used very often.

Comment: I don't see any reason why 'Non-Unitarian' would not fit the bill. More generally, when addressing all Christians except those belonging to a particular group X, I usually refer to them as 'Non-X' Christians.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Yes, I think it fits the bill, I'm just curious if there's some other term that has become the standard.

Answer (score 2):

98% of Christians are Trinitarian. Unitarians make up a huge majority of those that are not. However "Unitarian" is also the name of a number of denominations, and so tended to be avoided unless applied to those denominations. This makes it not very helpful to refer to those that are not Unitarian.

The number of Binitarians is extremely small (tens of thousands) and many people will divide Christians into Trinitarians and Unitarians, neglecting the outlying exceptions.

If you had to make such a reference then "non-Unitarian" would be fine, as long as you make it clear whether you mean those not in the denominations or a more general meaning.

Comment: This section from a Wikipedia article on Unitarianism is helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarianism#Terminology

Comment: It would be convenient if "**u**nitiarian" referred to the doctrine, while "**U**nitarian" referred to the denomination.  Unfortunately, most people capitalize "trinitarian" for the doctrine, and it's not very likely that is going to change.

Comment: "Trinitarian" is the correct capitalization, because it is derived from a proper noun, Trinity.